# saturation level of Kool Mu material

Tags: power-supply, magnetics, flyback

I have a toroidal core which has effective area of .656 cm^2 from magnetics , in [magnetics page](https://www.mag-inc.com/Products/Powder-Cores/Kool-Mu-Cores/Learn-More-about-Kool-Mu-Cores.aspx) they say it has 10,500 gauss saturation level (about 1 tesla!).

so.. when designing a flyback "transformer"(or coupled inductor), should I use this value of 1T as the saturation limit?  or should I use less value to decrease the losses?

## edit

[image]

It seems from this photo that it's okay but considering the imperfection of winding should i use a lower value?

Comment: Don't use the saturation limit, use values from the chart, at 100kHz and only 1kGauss  you've already got 1W/cm3 of loss. Seeing as it looks like a slope of 2 orders of magnitude loss per order of magnitude flux density, that would be *100W* of loss per cm3 at 100kHz @ 10kG!

Comment: Almost any flyback transformer will be core loss limited. For very obscure designs you may get away with kool-my but your first choise should be gapped ferrite for any flyback.

Comment: @winny I know but gapped ferrite cores are not availabe in my country and it doesn't worth shipping and I have a toroidal core from an old power supply (and i can use it for this application) so I decided to use it..

Comment: Digi-Key shipps all over the world and you can find plenty on eBay too. Unless you go into deep CCM, your core losses will be a problem. Find a ferrite transformer instead and gap it manually with paper and tape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to design to **all** limits, thermal as well as magnetic.

When deciding the maximum flux density to use, the frequency is important. A simple model of what's going on is that a core loses a certain amount of energy as it cycles once round its hysteresis loop. In this model, core dissipation is proportional to frequency.

In practice, the faster the core is taken round the loop, the higher the energy lost, so the power dissipation is proportional to a power higher than 1 of the frequency. Unfortunately, the KoolMu loss data is only given at 100kHz, and gives no hint of how it changes with frequency. In general, if something is not specified, you can expect it to be worse than you think rather than better, so this lack should be a warning that perhaps 100kHz is the highest useful frequency you can use.

The frequency is important in a flyback, as it works entirely by stored energy, so power throughput (assuming constant stored energy, which is of course not true) rises with frequency as well.

If you intend to use 100kHz or less for the frequency, then you can be reasonably safe in assuming that the core power loss will fall at least as fast as linearly with frequency, and so can increase your projected flux density to get a tolerable power loss at your chosen frequency. Once you have reached such a low frequency that you are permitted more than 1T, *then* you are limited by saturation.